# Google App Engine and openid4java - javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection is a restricted class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

I want to use openid authentication for my Google App engine project. For this I'm trying to use the openid4java library v0.9.6, but I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

The problem is pretty obvious and I found an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/issues/detail?id=160) saying that openid4java doesn't work with GAE since revision 658. The fix I tried was to checkout the code from revision 657 build it and use the resulting jar. No luck, I got the exact same error.

Any ideas of other workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the openid4java uses apache httpclient which is not allowed on GAE for https.

There's some workarounds -- you might have to unpackage the openid4java and replace code to use URLFetch instead of httpclient.

Here is one [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/openid4java/browse_thread/thread/42859dd18a15528f) that might help.